# haml linebreaks

Tags: haml, line-breaks

```
- if @likelist
          You like
          = @likelist.products.size
          products.
          = link_to "Likelist", likelist_path
```

this results in ugly linebreaks -->

```
     <div id='likelist_link'>
        You like
        1
        products.
        <a href="/likelist">Likelist</a>
      </div>
```

is there a way to get everything in one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- if @likelist
  You like #{@likelist.products.size} products. #{link_to "Likelist", likelist_path}
```